# Multiple mySQL joins in a PDO query

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a question about a complex mySQL query involving a users table, posts table, and comments table with 2 relationship tables for the comments. Basically I need to call all comments of a certain post and retrieve the name of the user which posted the comment. My table structure is as follows:

```
users:
--Fields:
----id
----name
----email
----password

posts:
--Fields:
----id
----post_title
----post_category
----post_content
----image_url
----created_at

comments:
--Fields:
----id
----comment
----mood
----created_at

post_comments (which holds the relationship between the post and the comment):
--Fields:
----id
----post_id
----comment_id

user_comments (which holds the relationship between the user and the comment):
--Fields:
----id
----user_id
----comment_id
```

So far I've written the query to retrieve the comments by topic id as:

```
SELECT pc.id, c.id AS comment_id, c.comment, c.mood, p.id AS post_id 
FROM post_comments pc 
INNER JOIN posts p ON pc.post_id=p.id 
INNER JOIN comments c ON pc.comment_id=p.id 
WHERE pc.post_id=:post_id
```

This works perfectly but I'm not sure how to go further as far as calling the username through the user_comment relationship table.

Comment: Thanks for the edit juergen d. Should have done that.

Comment: A question about your data structure: why do you have m:n relationship between post and comment (a post has several comments; a comment can belong to more than one post)? Usually, you have a 1:n relationship in this case (a post has several comments; a comment belongs to only one post).

Comment: Yes, a post can have several comments but a comment only belongs to one post. What would you recommend for the data structure? I'm not that knowledgeable about data structures and queries.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a proposed model change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like

```
SELECT
    users.name
FROM
    post_comments
JOIN
    comments
    ON comments.id = post_comments.comment_id
JOIN
    user_comments
    ON user_comments.comment_id = comments.id
JOIN
    users
    ON users.id = user_comments.user_id
WHERE
    post_comments.post_id = 1
```

Unless you need a field of your `posts` table in the query, I would start from `post_comments` (otherwise start with `posts`).

As discussed in the comments, a 1:n relationship can be represented with a column on one table to reference the other table.

In your case:

```
users:
--Fields:
----id
----name
----email
----password

posts:
--Fields:
----id
----post_title
----post_category
----post_content
----image_url
----created_at

comments:
--Fields:
----id
----post_id (which holds the relationship between the post and the comment)
----user_id (which holds the relationship between the user and the comment)
----comment
----mood
----created_at
```

Therefore, the query would change to:

```
SELECT
    users.name
FROM
    comments
JOIN
    users
    ON users.id = comments.user_id
WHERE
    comments.post_id = 1
```

A rule of thumb is:

- 1:n relationship (e.g. book has many pages, a page belongs to exactly one book)

  -> 2 tables (table `pages` includes a `book_id` column referencing the primary key of the `books` table)
- n:m relationship (e.g. a recipe has many ingredients, an ingredient can be used in many recipes)

  -> 3 tables (table `recipes`, table `ingredients`, table `ingredients_recipes` with `recipe_id` and `ingredient_id`)

Comment: Please see my comment on your question. Unless you have very special business rules, your data model (thus a lot of queries as well) could be simplified even more

Comment: Yes, that actually looks a lot better. And I guess I would add a user_id field to the posts table as well for the post author.

Comment: Yes, if the following is true: A post is created by (belongs to) one user